Getting error when tried to run React project
Every time I try creating a React app, I get following error:
PS C:\Users\Tashs November\Desktop\Event Management> npm create vite@lite
npm error code SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN
npm error request to https://registry.npmjs.org/create-vite failed, reason: self-signed certificate in certificate chain
npm error A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\Tashs November\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-07-31T08_45_49_900Z-debug-0.log

PS C:\Users\Tashs November\Desktop\Event Management> npm create vite@latest
npm error code SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN
npm error errno SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN

I tried opening a react folder using the following commands in hopes of it creating the actual app but it does not run:

npm create vite@latest
npm create vite@lite
npx create-react-app events management


Are you connected to a corporate network or VPN? I had this same error but it only happened when connected to the VPN. If that's the case, you might need to check with your IT

Do you check your system timezone/clock to ensure that SSL is working correctly?

Disabling strict-ssl mode may remove this error  npm set strict-ssl false

this is probably an issue with your network / proxy / firewall.
